# Is in python 2.7.10 '[[]]*2' different than ' [[],[]] ' ? Aren't they both same?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was solving a problem using python2 and I used 
'*seq= [[]]*2*' because I wanted this '[[],[]]. But I got wrong answer.
Then I tested it in IDLE like this:

```
>>>s=[[],[]]
>>>seq=[[]]*2
>>>seq
[[], []]
>>>s[0].append(5)
>>>s
[[5],[]]
>>>seq[0].append(5)
>>>seq
[[5],[5]]
```

I am totally confused. Can anyone help me? Please.

Comment: the test `[[]]*2 == [[],[]]` is True when I tested it, are you sure that is the code you tried?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen : Actually brother, when I did this 'seq=[[],[]]' and then did this 'seq[0].append(5)', the value of 'seq' became [[5],[]].

But when I did this, 'seq=[[]]*2' and then did 'seq[0].append(5)', then the value of 'seq' became [[5],[5]].

This is haunting me.

Comment: ok in that case yes this is a duplicate of the one posted.

Comment: Yeah...Sorry about that.